# Filtering by Foreign Key in ViewSet, django-rest-framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

I want my api to return certain objects from a database based on the foreign key retrieved from the url path. If my url looks like `api/get-club-players/1` I want every player object with matching club id (in this case `club.id == 1`). I'm pasting my code down below:

models.py

```
class Club(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    club = models.ForeignKey(Club, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)

    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

serialziers.py

```
class ClubSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Club
        fields = 'id', 'owner', 'name'

class PlayerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = 'id', 'name', 'offense', 'defence', 'club', 'position'
```

views.py, This is the part where I get the most trouble with:

```
class ClubViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Club.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ClubSerializer

class PlayerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Player.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PlayerSerializer

class GetClubPlayersViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def list(self, request):
        queryset = Player.objects.all()
        serializer = PlayerSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        

    def retrieve(self,request, clubId):
        players = Player.objects.filter(club=clubId, many=True)
        if not players:
            return JsonResponse({'error': "No query found!"})
        else:
            serializer = PlayerSerializer(players)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

urls.py

```
from rest_framework import routers
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import (GameViewSet, PlayerViewSet, ClubViewSet,
 GetClubPlayersViewSet, create_club, set_roster)

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'clubs', ClubViewSet, basename="clubs")
router.register(r'players', PlayerViewSet, basename="players")
router.register(r'get-club-players', GetClubPlayersViewSet, basename="club-players")

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

**EDIT:**
Now views.py looks like that:

```
class GetClubPlayersViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    queryset = Player.objects.all()

    def list(self, request):
        serializer = PlayerSerializer(self.queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        clubId = kwargs['get-club-players']
        players = Player.objects.filter(club=clubId, many=True)
        if not players:
            return JsonResponse({'error': "No query found!"})
        else:
            serializer = PlayerSerializer(players)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get-club-players/` returns all of the player objects, but when I ad a clubId into url I get this error:
[image]
[image]

**EDIT 2**:

```
class GetClubPlayersViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    queryset = Player.objects.all()
    
    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryParams = self.request.GET.get('abc')
        if queryParams is None:
            queryset = Player.objects.none()
        else:
            queryset = Player.objects.filter(club = queryParams)
            serializer = PlayerSerializer(queryset)
        return Response(serializer.data)
    
    def list(self, request):
        serializer = PlayerSerializer(self.queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get url parameters using kwargs attribute. You will need to modify the signature of your retrieve method for it.

```
def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    clubId = kwargs['get-club-players']
    players = Player.objects.filter(club=clubId, many=True)
    ....
```

**EDIT**

For the queryset error, it is due to DRF requiring either the `queryset` class attribute or implementation of `get_queryset()` function. In your case, you can get around it like this:

```
class GetClubPlayersViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):    
    queryset = Player.objects.all()

    def list(self, request):
        serializer = PlayerSerializer(self.queryset, many=True)
```

Comment: I get a "Cannot apply DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly on a view that does not set `.queryset` or have a `.get_queryset()` method." error now. Do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: I got another error, this time a KeyError at this line `clubId = self.kwargs['get-club-players']` when I tried to enter this url `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get-club-players/10/`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Try this new one. I accidentally left self.kwargs instead of kwargs

Comment: Same error I uploaded screenshot of this error and the piece of code I changed

Comment: That is weird. Try `clubId = kwargs.get('get-club-players')`

Comment: Another error: `Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field 'name' on serializer 'PlayerSerializer'.` can you point me to some tutorial or documentation? I think it would be better if I make this veiwset once again or try something different

Comment: The only one I can point you to is [DRF documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#request-parsing) that explains URL parameters retrieval. Take a look at the `query_params` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

So you can define your queryset like -

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryParams == self.request.GET.get('abc') # get queryparameter from url
    if queryParams is None:
        #queryset = anyModel.objects.all()
        queryset = anyModel.objects.none()
    else:
        queryset = anyModel.objects.filter(anyProperty = queryParams)
     return queryset
```

and your url will be like -

```
api/get-club-players/?abc=1
```

this **abc** can be **id** or any other property from the model.

Use this get_queryset logic in your retrieve method.

Comment: It returned all of the objects

Comment: request.GET is a very bad practice of retrieving URL parameters. Specially more so when it is used in create, update or delete views. @mateuszlaczynski if you are using this method of URL parameters retrieval, make sure to [read through this article](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#request-parsing). It should work fine for this view where you are only getting the model objects.

Comment: Well use this on get request only and if you configure this properly it will return filtered queryset. show your retrieve method.

Comment: Check out Edit 2

Comment: But why are you returning queryset, dont retuern queryset . defined serializer = PlayerSerializer(quesryset) and return Response(serializer.data) as u did in list.

Comment: I updated Edit 2 as you said and got the same results. All objects are still displayed in `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get-club-players/?abc=10`

Answer (score 0):

`rest_framework.viewsets.ViewSet` has an attribute named `lookup_field` which you can override. By default the value of `lookup_field` is `id`.

When adding the viewset in router, the `lookup_field` is added as the argument name in the url (e.g. `/api/get-club-players/:id/`).

You can either override the `lookup_field` of `GetClubPlayersViewSet` or access the correct kwargs key by changing
`clubId = kwargs['get-club-players']` to `clubId = kwargs['id']`

Or a bit of both:

```
class GetClubPlayersViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
    lookup_field = "clubId"
    queryset = Player.objects.all()

    # ....

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        clubId = kwargs[self.lookup_field]
        players = Player.objects.filter(club=clubId, many=True)
        if not players:
            return JsonResponse({'error': "No query found!"})
        else:
            serializer = PlayerSerializer(players)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```